# What is + in F#?

Tags: function, f#, operator-keyword, reduce, fold

Why can't I do something like

```
let sum = List.fold + 0 aListOfNumbers
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because if you write it that way, F# thinks that you're trying to call `+` with `List.fold` as its left argument and `0 aListOfNumbers` as its right argument.

To give an infix operator as an argument to a function you need to parenthesize it:

```
let sum = List.fold (+) 0 aListOfNumbers
```